# ion-toggle and ion-datetime empty until clicked

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've got a pure component taking an `param` object as input and using it to render a form in Ionic.

The form looks empty until clicked. After a click, it gets populated according to the input data.

Here is a sample :

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-pure-component",
    templateUrl: "template.html",
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ObservationComponent {
    @Input()
    public param;
}
```

Template:

```
<ion-item-group id="toggleParameters">
    <ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center>
        <ion-col col-auto>
            <p ion-text color="neutral">{{param.notify ? 'yes' : 'no'}}</p> <!-- This works -->
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col no-lines>
            <ion-item detail-none no-lines>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="param.notify"></ion-input>  <!-- This also works -->
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col no-lines>
            <ion-item detail-none no-lines>
                <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="param.notify"></ion-toggle> <!-- This doesn't -->
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-datetime class="inputLike"
                          displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                          pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY"
                          max="2100" min="2015"
                          cancelText="cancel"
                          doneText="ok"
                          [(ngModel)]="param.somedate"> <!-- Nor this -->
            </ion-datetime>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-item-group>
```

Parent component :

```
<my-pure-component [param]="{ notify: true, somedate: '2018-01-01' }">
</my-pure-component>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have used *ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush* Use default change detection mechanism by removing this ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush from child component.

Comment: Nope, it's the same without it